# How do you calculate the current and voltage when the emitter is grounded for saturation mode

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

For example, assume you have this transistor with a grounded emitter:

[image]

Since we are dealing with a saturation mode, \$v_{ce} = 0.2 \$ making the drop across the resistor 9.8 v. The current going through the collector is \$ I_c = 9.8/10 k\Omega = 9.8 mA \$ and assuming \$ \beta = 100 \$ then \$I_b = 0.098 mA \$. But \$v_c = I_c \times R_c = 9.8\$ volts. For a transistor to be considered in the saturation mode \$v_c < v_b \$

My textbook has some contradictory statements about saturation mode. In the beginning of the course, we learned that when a transistor is in saturation mode, the collector should read close to zero volts. The book now says that when a HIGH (> 2 volts) is applied to the input supplied to the transistor's base, it will cause the transistor to conduct and the collector voltage drops to a LOW. But in the calculation from above (assuming that it was done correctly), I can clearly see that the voltage on the collector is 9.8 volts, close to 10 volts and not anywhere close to zero or LOW.

EDIT: Am I suppose to assume that \$v_c = v_{cc} - I_c \times R_c = 0.2\$. Since the emitter is grounded, \$v_c = v_{ce}\$

Comment: Vc = 10V - Ic*Rc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make both assumptions about \$V_{ce} = 0.2V\$ and \$\beta = 100\$ at the same time; they are for two different modes of operation for the transistor (there's also a third mode where the transistor is in cutoff, and a fourth less common one in reverse active).

You start out assuming one of the possible states. For example, suppose I assume the transistor is saturated. Then \$V_{ce} = 0.2V\$ and \$V_{be} = 0.7V\$. You can then solve for base and collector currents using these assumptions for the BJT **and only these assumptions**.

The last step is to check your assumptions. For example, to make sure the transistor isn't actually in the linear active region must check that \$\beta I_{b} \gg I_{c}\$. So let's say in your case you get \$I_{c} = 9.8 mA\$ and \$I_{b} = 9.8 \mu A\$.  Well clearly our assumption about saturation was bad because \$\beta I_{b} = 980 \mu A\$, which is less than our calculated \$I_{c}\$. We must then start over with new assumptions and re-solve the problem.

Instead, suppose \$I_b = 2 mA\$. Then \$\beta I_b = 200mA\$, which is much greater than \$I_c\$, so now the saturation assumption is correct.

Note: \$\beta I_b \gg I_c\$ is kind of a vague limit. Typically we use at least 10 times bigger for saturation.

For solving assuming the BJT is forward active, you would assume \$\beta I_b = I_c\$ **and only this assumption**. To check it (against saturation), simply make sure \$0.2V < V_{ce}\$.

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation of the collector current is correct. So let's focus on calculating the base current.

> Since we are dealing with a saturation mode, vce=0.2 making the drop across the resistor 9.8 v. The current going through the collector is Ic=9.8/10kΩ=9.8mA and assuming β=100 then Ib=0.098mA.

β is a characteristic of the transistor in forward-active mode, and doesn't apply in saturation.

Simply use the forward drop of the be junction, \$V_{be}\approx{}0.7\ \mathrm{V}\$. Then the base resistor determines the current, \$I_b=\dfrac{V_{in}-0.7\ \mathrm{V}}{10\ \mathrm{k\Omega}}\$.

> I can clearly see that the voltage on the collector is 9.8 volts

You just got mixed up here. The voltage across the collector **resistor** was 9.8 V. The voltage across the transistor from emitter to collector is 0.2 V. In fact, you got the 9.8 V number by assuming \$v_{ce}=0.2\ \mathrm{V}\$.

Answer (score 0):

VC does NOT equal 9.8V.   It is 10 - 9.8 = 0.2 as in your assumption.

The 0.2V is only an approximation - depending upon the transistor it may be as low as a handful of millivolts.